# crystal report: print missing records

Tags: crystal-reports

i want to print missing records in crystal report .
i am using below formula in the report and i have placed this formula in details b section.
details a has normal report fields.

formula:

```
local numbervar firstemp; // first Emp#
local numbervar nextemp;  // next Emp#
local numbervar diff;     // difference between firstemp and nextemp
local numbervar increase; // increment for missing Emp#'s
local numbervar result;
increase := 0;
firstemp := tonumber({getRptSalesSummery;1.Bill_Id});  
nextemp := tonumber(next({getRptSalesSummery;1.Bill_Id}));
nextemp := nextemp -1;
diff := nextemp - firstemp;
if nextemp = firstemp
then ""
else (
while diff >= 1 
do (
diff := diff - 1;
increase := increase + 1;
result := firstemp + increase;

exit while;
);
totext (result,"0000") & chr(13);
)
```

this formula is not giving me range.
for example if in report there is range of 1 to 10 and 6,7,8,9 is missing records, then if i check in the report its printing 1 to 5 and 6 as missing then directly 10, but its not giving me 7,8,9.

basically i required range of missing records

Comment: hi it has worked...i have changed the formula..

Comment: this is the change i made in formula and its giving me range of missing records..thanks
if nextemp = firstemp
then ""
else (
while diff >= 1 
do (
diff := diff - 1;
increase := increase + 1;
result := firstemp + increase;
temp:= temp & totext (result ,"0")& "        No Bill" & chr(13)  ;
//exit while;
);
//totext (result,"") ;
temp ;
)